# Post Request message Not being displayed in the App when sending post req from ui front end

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, post

> I am building a chat app which displays the Name and the message to be
> sent using node.js ,express.js,socket.io , mongodb
>
> But the below question comes up during the Node.js ,express,js part
> (socket.io and mongodb not used till now). The question is the code
> should have displayed the user and message below but in my case it is
> simply a blank

[image: What i expect]     [image]

> **SERVER.JS FILE**

```
var express =require("express")

var bodyParser = require("body-parser")

var app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

var messages=[

    {name: "Dibin",message:"HELLO"},

    {name: "Subin",message:"Hi"}
]

 

app.get('/messages',(req,res)=>{

res.send(messages)

})

app.post('/messages',(req,res)=>{

    messages.push(req.body)

    res.sendStatus(200)
})


var server=app.listen(3010, () => {

console.log("Server is listening on port",server.address().port )

})`
`
```

**INDEX.HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" 
         integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" 
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
         integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" 
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>   

    <body>

        <div class="container">
        <br>
           <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4"> Send Message </h1>
            <br>
            
            <input id ="name" class="form-control" placeholder ="Name">
            <br>
            <textarea id ="message" class="form-control" placeholder ="Message"></textarea>
            <br>
            <button id="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>  
           </div>
        
           <div id="messages">
               
           </div>   
        </div>
         
         
     <script>
         $(()=> {

           $("#send").click(() =>{ 
        
            var message ={name: $("#name").val(), message: $("#message").val()}
            postMessage(message)

         })
        getMessages()
        })

         function addMessages(message){
          
            $("#messages").append(`<h4> ${message.name} </h4> <p> ${message.message}</p>`)


         }

         function getMessages(){

            $.get("http://localhost:3010/messages",data=>{

                console.log(data)
            })
         }


         function postMessage(message) {

            $.post('http://localhost:3010/messages', message )

           }

     </script>

    </body>   

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `extended: true`

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```

From official [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions):

> bodyParser.urlencoded([options])
> Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.
> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body). This object will contain key-value pairs, where the value can be a string or array (when extended is false), or any type (when extended is true).